# Compute $\iiint_V (z+2)\, dx\, dy \,dz$ where $V$ is the region bounded by two planes and a paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Compute $$\iiint_V (z+2)\, dx\, dy\, dz$$ where $V$ is the region bounded by the planes $z=1$, $z=3$ and the paraboloid $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}=z$.
I think that the projection of $V$ on the $xy$ plane is $D=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2| \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}\le 9\}$. Thus, we have $$\iiint_V (z+2)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\iint_D\left(\int_1^3 (z+2)\,dz \right)dx\,dy=8\iint_D dx\,dy$$

and this is now easy to compute (I just need to make the substituion $x=5r\cos \theta$, $y=3r\sin \theta$), but I am not really sure whether what I did is correct. So, please let me know if I reduced the triple integral to a double integral correctly.

Comment: No, this isn't correct. Why do you believe you are allowed to separate integrals like this? The approach I would take is $$\iiint_V(z+2)dV=\int\limits_1^3\int\limits_0^{3\sqrt z}\int\limits_0^{5\sqrt{9z-y^2}/3}(z+2)dxdydz$$

Comment: @DonThousand I am kind of a newbie when it comes to this kind of integrals, so this is why my attempt may be blatantly wrong (I am not sure that I even understand the theory properly yet.

Comment: The thought of projection in XY-plane in good but it would work if you were integrating wrt. $z$ first and you were not bound between two planes. Also remember that the surface is $z = r^2$ (after transformation $x = 5 r \cos\theta, y = 3 r \sin\theta$) so $z$ and $r$ are not independent.

Comment: @MathLover I see, so projection in the $xy$ plane is good when we don't have our $z$ bounded between two planes. I thought that maybe I should have projected on a different plane maybe?

Comment: Yes if you were to find volume for $z = r^2$ below $z = 3$ plane then you know the max radius is $\sqrt3$ in plane $z = 3$. So you could first integrate wrt $z$ between paraboloid surface and plane $z = 3$ which is $r^2 \leq z \leq 3$ and then for $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt3$ and then wrt $\theta$. When you are between two planes. for part of the circle in $z = 3$, your shells are between planes and then for part of it between plane  and paraboloid. So that will mean split integral. The method used in the below answer is disc method and that is easier here.

Comment: @Math Lover I see. Another thing that I thought that might have worked is the so called cross sections method (https://mathinsight.org/triple_integral_cross_section_method). Would this have been fruitful?

Comment: That is what the below answer does. Cross sections method in the link is the disc method (for circular cross-sections) I referred to in above comment.

Comment: @MathLover I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct. Note that at no point you have use that fact that, when $z=1$, then you will be dealing only with the circle $\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\middle|\,\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}9=1\right\}$. However, your idea of doing $x=5r\cos\theta$ and $y=3r\sin\theta$ is fine. Doing this, your integral becomes$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3\int_0^{\sqrt z}15r(z+2)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta=250\pi.$$

Comment: Carlos Santos Thank you, I am really a newbie to this kind of problems. So, what you are saying is that I have $V=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | 1\le z\le 3, \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}\le z \}$ and I should make the substituion $x=5r\cos \theta$, $y=3r\sin \theta$ and $z=z$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Carlos Santos Thank you very much! This indeed makes sense. One more question because, as I said, I am really new to this: what if I had written $\int_1^3\left(\iint_D (z+2)dx dy\right)dz$ instead of $\iint_D\left(\int_1^3 (z+2)\,dz \right)dx\,dy$? Would it have been correct?

Comment: I don't think so. That use, I could compute that integral and see if it gives the right answer, but I don't see why should that be the case.

Comment: Carlos Santos I see, thank you!